# Is there a AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION Bluetooth permission interaction?

Tags: android

I have a very simple line of code:

```
audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
```

However, recently on 4.0+ devices, I am seeing a crash due to this line saying it requires the bluetooth permission.

To be more precise, the error I'm seeing says:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Need BLUETOOTH permission
```

at the line of my setMode.

I have the `MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS` permission, however I do not see how this interacts with bluetooth, so I am looking for a confirmation of whether or not I truly need the BLUETOOTH permission for MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From a logical point of view, there is no way that `AudioManager` would use Bluetooth and thus need `android.permission.BLUETOOTH`.

From a source code point of view, `setMode()` needs only `android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS`:

- [`AudioManager:1425`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/media/java/android/media/AudioManager.java)

  ```
  public void setMode(int mode) {
      IAudioService service = getService();
      try {
          service.setMode(mode, mICallBack);
      } catch (RemoteException e) {
          Log.e(TAG, "Dead object in setMode", e);
      }
  }
  ```
- [`AudioService:703`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/media/AudioService.java#AudioService.setMode%28int,android.os.IBinder%29)

  ```
  public void setMode(int mode, IBinder cb) {
      if (!checkAudioSettingsPermission("setMode()")) {
          return;
      }
  ```
- [`AudioService:1250`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/media/AudioService.java#AudioService.checkAudioSettingsPermission%28java.lang.String%29)

  ```
  boolean checkAudioSettingsPermission(String method) {
      if (mContext.checkCallingOrSelfPermission("android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS")
          == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
      return true;
      }
  String msg = "Audio Settings Permission Denial: " + method + " from pid="
      + Binder.getCallingPid()
      + ", uid=" + Binder.getCallingUid();
      Log.w(TAG, msg);
      return false;
  }
  ```

Comment: Yeah, I believe the issue is coming from OEM / special versions of Android. I put in a catch, for now. You answered my question perfectly, thank you.