# Bluetooth permission is missing - but my app doesn't use it

Tags: android, permissions, bluetooth, logcat

My Current app is pretty much working except that it occasionally throws an Error for which I have no explanation:

```
E/AudioManagerAndroid﹕ BLUETOOTH permission is missing!
```

No further infos given...
My App has nothing to do with Bluetooth, so i am wondering where this error comes from. 
The closest thing might be the ringtone manager that I access to get the default alarm tone to use for my notification.

Has anyone experienced the same, and possibly knows a fix?
It doesn't crash the app for me but I have the impression that it does crash the app on a testing friends phone (no logcat from him, because he is hundreds of miles away and doesn't know anything about these things)

Comment: Nexus device? I've seen this. Ignore it, it's not your fault. If you want to debug your friend's app, use ACRA.

Comment: No, Sony. Good new on the one side. Bad news, i have yet another bug in my app :( I'll look into ACRA, thank you

Comment: seems to happen on my opo too

Comment: I have the same on Moto G, BTW what is ACRA?

Comment: seems to be related to [this other post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417127/is-there-a-audiomanager-mode-in-communication-bluetooth-permission-interaction) but I have found that this error is actually more related to  `WebView`s ( [check the Chromimum's `AudioManagerAndroid` code line 590](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/media/+/32c515047512e7558e279819a99e26e0e512f5b6/base/android/java/src/org/chromium/media/AudioManagerAndroid.java) ) and [it has already been reported](https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=445)

Comment: It's 2016 and I just found that line in a logcat. :(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30679058/android-permission-app-crashes-needing-bluetooth-permission i think your answer is here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Permission: App crashes needing bluetooth permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30679058/android-permission-app-crashes-needing-bluetooth-permission)

Answer (score 1):

**Have you tried adding permission in AndroidManifest.xml?**

- Just in case, this is the command :

  <`uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />`

then run the program again to see if the issue has been fixed.

- Do your app transfer data via bluetooth?

E.g. transfer data in music player apps or transfer data to control light/fan to turn On/Off. If that's not the case I think there may be some kind of bugs with android IDE, it should be fixed when updating android studio to the latest version.

I know it's been almost a decade since you asked this one but I hope it helps :D .