# Android Permission: App crashes needing bluetooth permission

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I was recently creating an app that uses bluetooth. The problem is my app crashes when ever I start the bluetooth service. Here's my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="in.petalappstudio.fit" >

<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".bluetoothManager"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
    </service>
</application>
```

Now as you can see I have added permission for bluetooth and bluetooth admin.

How ever my app crashes and in LOGCAT the error is

```
"java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service " and is caused by
"java.lang.SecurityException: Need BLUETOOTH ADMIN permission: Neither user 10145 nor current process has android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN."
```

But I have added permission as you can see. Now why is this happening ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add one more permission :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Refe. : [Android Permission BLUETOOTH Manifest error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29786291/android-permission-bluetooth-manifest-error)

Note : also check device support Bluetooth feature or not using :

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" android:required="true" />
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't thought that way. :)

Comment: Yeh, I saw that and have added that too. It was helpful, thanks :)